# Facebook API set(change) params of apps.facebook.com URL

Tags: javascript, facebook

How do I change the get parameters of the `apps.facebook.com` URL with JavaScript?

For example, the user selects some photo, so the URL should change to `apps.facebook.com/myapp/?photo_id=23234` so the user can simply copy it and give some friend and the friend lands exactly on the same photo and not at the start(home) page.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript code as follows.

```
    top.location.href="whatever url";
```

Comment: I don't want to change location, only to change the get params.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the page to reload when the user chooses a photo, you're going to have to use pushState. You can use the History API:

```
history.pushState('null', 'null', 'http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?photo_id=23234');
```

You should include a fallback also.

Comment: I get Security error" code: "1000
on history.pushState('null', 'null', ...ook.com/myapp/p='+product.id);